# Triggering a keyframe animation on a specific js variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a sequence of animations that I require to start when the value of the js variable (trigger) equals 1. Frankly, I don’t know where to start. A internet search has not helped!

For a click event I’m using the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#forwards").click(function() {
        jQuery("#stone").addClass("reveal");
        jQuery("#forwards, #buttonbox").addClass("fadeOut");
        jQuery("#cover_2").addClass("fadeIncover_2").css('z-index', '10');
 jQuery("#left_plinth, #right_plinth, #left_pillar, #right_pillar, #head, #cornice,  #cornice_minor_left, #cornice_minor_right, #innerbox, #messagebox").addClass("fadeIn");
        jQuery("#screen").addClass("fadeOutSlower");
        jQuery("#accessbox").addClass("expandScreen");

    });
});
</script>
```

I’d really appreciate some help with this as my javascript knowledge is basic to say the least.
Many thanks
Philip

Note. I have already posted this on one other site.

Comment: where is variable `trigger` in your code you use `if` in your function

Comment: Sorry @Pravin, I haven't made my intentions clear I'm looking for a way to replace the click() function with a test to see if trigger ==1 and if it does to activate a sequence of keyframes.

Comment: Problem solved. I had forgotten to include a link to jQuery.(Blush)